# Parse Boolean Response using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm using **AFNetworking** in my Swift app. I make a `POST` request using `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` and receive response using `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`. HTTP status code is 200 and I get successful response.

However, I'm not able to parse Boolean response. On Postman, the response comes as Boolean (either true or false) but I'm not able to identify response object type in my code. Please see attached image showing response object.

[image]

Response on Postman

[image]

Tried parsing it as follows but `IF` condition doesn't satisfy.

```
if let isSuccess = response as? Bool {
     print(isSuccess)
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, if your app is written in Swift why not use Alamofire?

Comment: Just used to using AFNetworking :) Also, it's a team project and cannot take decision on my own.

Comment: Can you print response and share the output? Can you share code where **AFNetworking** infers other types except **Boolean**?

Comment: @Kamran: On printing response, I'm getting:
<74727565>

Comment: https://medium.com/sroze/ios-swift-and-afnetworking-get-response-data-and-status-code-in-case-of-failure-69cee3c33eb1

Comment: ‘{true}’ isn’t a valid JSON. Seems like a special case. You can try ‘JsonSerialization’ to verify if you can access ‘data’ from response. You can also try creating bool from data.

Comment: @Maverick try changing the response from backend with a key and value, that would be easy to handle.

Comment: @Kamran JsonResponseSerializer gives error. API is successful only with HTTPResponseSerializer.

Comment: @HarjotSingh Of course that's a convenience solution but there must be a way to handle it with AFNetworking

Comment: Yes, invalid JSON is the issue. You may have to use HTTPResponseSerializer for this particular request Or May have to catch the error in JSONSerializer and call completion with Boolean(kind of hack) if status is 200. But if you have an agreement with backend on response structure then it’s better to change on api side.

Comment: @Kamran If you read the question, I'm already using HTTPResponseSerializer which is giving me status 200 but it can be true or false depending upon request parameters and I need to know if returned Boolean is true or false.

Comment: It's resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55785751/3659227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server is sending 'true' or 'false' as JSON which is essentially invalid JSON. Henceforth, if I try to use `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, it gives error because returned JSON is not in correct format.

So I had to use `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` that returns response as `Data`. Then I converted this `Data` into `String` to retrieve 'true' or 'false' text.

```
if let isSuccessData = response as? Data {
    if let isSuccessText = String(data: isSuccessData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(isSuccessText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `response` object is of type `Any?`. Maybe try casting it as a boolean value in a safe way:

```
if let response = response as? Bool {
    // Do something with the response
}
```

Put a breakpoint inside the if statement to make it easier to see if the condition was met.